# How to write eagerly loading query on many to many relation with additional filtering and sorting

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, many-to-many, eager-loading

I need to create a eager loading query that will perform these tasks:

- Get parent Entity by id
- Filter child entities by criteria
- Sort child list of entities

My non-eager query looks like this:

```
var company = _dbContext.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == companyId);

if (company != null)
{
    company.CompanyProducts =
        company.CompanyProducts
               .Where(cp => cp.IsBuyable && cp.Product.IsPublished)
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Product.PublishDate)
               .ThenBy(c => c.Product.Name)
               .ToList();
}

return company;
```

Where Entities have this structure:

```
public class Company
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyProduct> CompanyProducts { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyProdcut
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public bool IsBuyable { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyProduct> CompanyProducts { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
      public MyDbContext() : base("name=connectionString")
      {
          Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
      }

      public virtual IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
      public virtual IDbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
      public virtual IDbSet<CompanyProduct> CompanyProducts { get; set; }

}
```

This is classic many to many relation that uses an entity in the middle to store addtional data.

```
Company -|---------|< CompanyProduct >|---------|- Product
```

How in this case I can rewrite the non-eager query to eager query, that will do everything in one SQL call? I tried to do it myself using the *.Include()* but I failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you did wrong but according to the EF documentation `.Include()` is how you Eargerly load something. For you one you should have in your query `... .ThenBy(c => c.Product.Name).Include("Company").Include("Product").ToList();` see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: @Avangar So what is wrong with,     company.CompanyProducts =
        company.CompanyProducts
.Include(x => x.Company).Include(x => x.Product)
               .Where(cp => cp.IsBuyable && cp.Product.IsPublished))
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Product.PublishDate)
               .ThenBy(c => c.Product.Name)
               .ToList();?

Comment: @Avanger Just based on what you are showing us. I am assuming this is a code first setup? If so, can you show us your constructor for your context?

Comment: @IdahoSixString Yes this is code first. The context doesn't have any settings in the constructor.

Comment: @IdahoSixString putting Include like this. Gives "Cannot resolve symbol 'Include'". Intelisense doesn't show that Include is possible in that place.
    
    company.CompanyProducts =
            company.CompanyProducts
                   .Include(x => x.Company)
                   .Include(x => x.Product)
                   .Where(cp => cp.IsBuyable && cp.Product.IsPublished))
                   .OrderByDescending(c => c.Product.PublishDate)
                   .ThenBy(c => c.Product.Name)
                   .ToList();

Comment: @Toxicable Same goes for this solution I as above. I also get the error about symbol and Intelisense says that Include is not allowed there.

    
    company.CompanyProducts =
            company.CompanyProducts
                   .Where(cp => cp.IsBuyable && cp.Product.IsPublished))
                   .OrderByDescending(c => c.Product.PublishDate)
                   .ThenBy(c => c.Product.Name)
       .Include(x => x.Company)
                   .Include(x => x.Product)
                   .ToList();

Comment: That the overall the problem. I can't find the way to keep the filtering and includes in one query.

Comment: I've added the DbContext class.

Comment: @Avangar I assure you it is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx. Add reference to namespace System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider it the best approach but you can have a `.Include()` statement in the two positions I have shown below. If you include it in the first query then I think you'd be fine to use your method for the second one but I havn't tested to not certain about that.

The reason why you can't use it in the positions in your example is becasue it can only be used on a IQueryable() object, of which Company and ICollection is not.

```
var _dbContext = new MyDbContext();
var company = _dbContext.Companies.Include("").SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == companyId);

var products = _dbContext.Companies.Include("").SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == companyId)
                ?.CompanyProducts
                .Where(cp => cp.IsBuyable && cp.Product.IsPublished)
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Product.PublishDate)
                .ThenBy(c => c.Product.Name)
                .ToList();

if(company != null)
{
    company.CompanyProducts = products;
}
return company;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var company = _dbContext.Companies.Include(x => x.CompanyProducts).Includex => x.CompanyProducts.Select(y => y.Company).Includex => x.CompanyProducts.Select(y => y.Product).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == companyId);
if (company != null)
{
    company.CompanyProducts =
        company.CompanyProducts
           .Where(cp => cp.IsBuyable && cp.Product.IsPublished)
           .OrderByDescending(c => c.Product.PublishDate)
           .ThenBy(c => c.Product.Name)
           .ToList();
}

return company;
```

To get the lambda include make sure to add reference to System.Data.Entity.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176380(v=vs.113).aspx